# Unusual harmonic data reading from phototransistor in a simple arduino setup

Tags: arduino, phototransistor, arduino-uno

I have a very simple circuit for detecting ambient light readings with an arduino, but I'm noticing a sinusoidal pattern to the readings I'm getting that are hard to pin down the source of. How do I eliminate the noise so I get a more or less constant reading?

My circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0kqTS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My code is simply:

```
int analogPin = 0;     

int val = 0;           

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);              
}

void loop()
{
  val = analogRead(analogPin);     
  Serial.println(val);             
  delay(33);
}
```

I graphed the results and it looks like this, oscilating between the values of 175 and 110, on a scale that goes from 0 to 1000 normally:

[image]

The period is about 8.5 seconds between crests, with downward blips about once every 1.4 seconds. Nothing in the light around me would explain this obviously... what's going on? How do I get more consistent values?

### Solution

I took random samples over the course of the sample period and that seemed to help out a lot.

```
int analogPin = 0;     // potentiometer wiper (middle terminal) connected to 
analog pin 3
                       // outside leads to ground and +5V
int val = 0;           // variable to store the value read
int maxwait = 200;
int varwait = 2000;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);              //  setup serial
}

void loop()
{
  long sum = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int endTime = millis() + maxwait;
  while(millis() < endTime){
    sum += analogRead(analogPin);
    count++;
    delayMicroseconds(rand() % varwait);
  }
  Serial.println(sum / count);
}
```

Comment: Any artificial light sources nearby (or computer screens) The 8.5sec cycle could be a result of your sample rate and the fluctuations in the light. Try to add a different delay in sampling and see what that gives you.

Comment: How Do your delay value affect the measured response?  So there is no line frequency FL flicker aliasing?

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense. I just didn't expect it to affect it that much, I thought there might be a sort of inherent smoothing out that the transistor might do.

I've got lights and one monitor at 60hz, and one monitor at 144hz, which would explain the little blip. Averaging random samples over the same time period gives me much better results. I've gotta sleep now, but I'll definitely explore this more later.

Comment: You probably won't see this pattern during daylight hours...

Comment: You can also try to illuminate your measurement system with an old flashlight, with a halogen or tungsten filament bulb instead of the existing ambient light, and then you would be able to tell if the noise comes from something else.

Comment: @AdamSpurgin: the photodiode in your circuit diagram is poled the wrong way. If it really was poled that way you would read about 4.4V independent of Illumination.

Comment: Yeah, probably. I'm a CS student by education, the little nuances are a little arcane to me.  It did respond in a way that I expected though, aside from the harmonics.

Comment: @AdamSpurgin: you probably poled it correctly in your real circuit but you had it first drawn the wrong way in the schematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably an aliasing effect of your sampling frequency with the line frequency that powers some fluorescent or LED lights.

E.g. if the sampling frequency is alsmost a multiple of 50 or 60Hz (depending on your electrical power system), but not exactly: if the difference between sampling frequency and multiple of power line frequency is just 1/8.5s = 0.118 Hz you get this sinusoidal response.

See following image taken from [Sampling sinusoidal functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions):
[image]

The red sinusoidal line represents the variation of light intensisty by line frequency (50/60Hz).
The blue sinusoidal line represents your output.
The black dots represent your sampling events (it works also if they are even more spread as shown in the image; i.e. e.g. sampling in every n-th period).